# Comparing csv values to values in txt file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, filter, grep

i have the following situation:

1. csv with list of windows hotfixes and cve named out.csv
   [out.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4SeE.png)
2. list of cve named cvelist
   [cve_list.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxfYV.png)

I need a python script that will do the following:

Go through each row in out.csv;
Filter every column for values in txt
Export first column AND ALL columns that contain values that are in cve_list.txt

*Real csv and txt are much larger than example.
PS i would use grep but it dont returns proper value,eg he should return only first line and red strings not white:
[grep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTljW.png)

I had 0 luck with this so i don know where to start

Comment: Welcome to SO. Instead of images, could you provide the output of `head -n3 out.csv cve_list.csv`? Also, what grep arguments did you use?

Comment: Ty Fravadona, as for grep the syntax is following: 
cat out.csv | grep -f cve_list.txt
Output: KB5022903, CVE-2021-1678 CVE-2021-26414 CVE-2021-26424 CVE-2021-26425 CVE-2021-26435 CVE-2021-26442 CVE-2021-34481 CVE-2021-34483 CVE-2021-34484 CVE-2021-34533 CVE-2021-34535 CVE-2021-36927 CVE-2021-36936 CVE-2021-36937 CVE-2021-36947 CVE-2021-36953 CVE-2021-36955 CVE-2021-36958 CVE-2021-36959 CVE-2021-36960 CVE-2021-36961 CVE-2021-36962 CVE-2021-36963